# SOAP request sent from SUDS has '\n' in xml tags

Tags: python-3.x, soap, soap-client, suds

I am using SUDS to call a SOAP web service. How ever the when I see the XML sent by SUDS, lines breaks '\n' characters are added to xml tags.

I am assuming \n in xml does not make an issue. But is there a way I can remove \n from the xml generated by SUDS.

sample given below:

```
<ns0:Body><ns1:getMemberEligibility><ns1:memberEligibilityRequest>\n                <clientId>1</clientId>\n                <ns7:customerId>732</ns7:customerId>\n                <ns7:firstName>PPP</ns7:firstName>\n                <ns7:groupExternalId>0001</ns7:groupExternalId>\n                <ns7:lastName>MMM</ns7:lastName>\n                <ns7:birthDate>1950-03-21</ns7:birthDate>\n                <ns7:memberId>19500123MMMPPP</ns7:memberId>\n                <ns7:relationship>\n                    <code>01</code>\n                </ns7:relationship>\n</ns1:memberEligibilityRequest></ns1:getMemberEligibility></ns0:Body>
```

Comment: did you figure out a proper way to resolve this? i am doing it with brute-force search&replace